# Website hosted in IIS 6 becoming slow

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

My website has recently becoming slow now a days. The website is hosted on IIS 6.0, this website is also using 8 other (supporting services) webservices hosted on the same application pool. What is the best practice for deploying these kind of applications? Will hosting the services and website on diff application pool reduces the whole site slowness?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should [improve](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true) things. Each application pool gets its own worker process, which means more threads and potentially more memory for each application.

There are other considerations for performance:

- Identify your bottlenecks - e.g. SQL, Network Bandwidth, CPU, worker threads etc. [Perfmon counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are a good starting point
- Once done, you can then adopt an appropriate strategy, e.g. SQL Indexing, Caching, Data Pagination, or app Code optimisation. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx)